# MYSQL Query don't return which have no relation on Join Query

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query to get all data from table "User" and corresponding "Transaction" count from table "Service" . I've 100 user on table 1 . But currently only 2 user have relation with service table. Now my query just return two results. But I used left outer query for getting all users which have not relation with Service table.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT users.*, 
count(service.recipient_number) as total_transaction FROM `users`
LEFT OUTER join service ON users.id = service.office_id
WHERE (users.del_status = 0 and service.del_status = 0 and 
users.type="agency") 
group BY users.office_name
```

Present output:

```
 Username  total_transaction
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   Dhaka         2
   Ctg           1
```

Desire Output:

```
  Username  total_transaction
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   Dhaka         2
   Ctg           1
   Sylhet        0
   Comilla       0
   Mym           0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.office_name,
       count(service.recipient_number) as total_transaction 
FROM `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN service ON users.id = service.office_id
                        AND service.del_status = 0
                        AND year(curdate()) = year(service.creation_time) 
                        AND month(curdate()) = month(service.creation_time)
WHERE users.del_status = 0  
AND users.type = 'agency'
GROUP BY users.office_name
```

You need to put the `where` conditions regarding the joined table, directly into the `join`.

Why? Because the `where` clause filters the complete result set. But the `join` conditions filter only the joined table result.

Comment: Hi , Sorry I missed one thing. Here is a condition for current month checking also. But when i add this, it return only two.     "SELECT users.office_name,
       count(service.recipient_number) as total_transaction 
FROM `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN service ON users.id = service.office_id
                        AND service.del_status = 0
WHERE users.del_status = 0  
AND users.type = 'agency'
AND (year(curdate()) = year(service.creation_time) and month(curdate()) = month(service.creation_time))
GROUP BY users.office_name
order by total_transaction desc"

Comment: From which table are those columns?

Comment: Those column are on Service table

Comment: Then put those condtions in the JOIN too.